# REST Client not generating Webhook Events in Sandbox

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-webhooks

I am unable to get the Paypal provided REST client  (the client side js) to trigger webhook events in the sandbox to receive payment confirmation on my server app.

Here's what I can do/ have done:

I have created a REST app in the sandbox.

I have subscribed to all webhook events.

I am able to pay with the client app using my sandbox client id and see see the payment reflected in the facilitator account.

I am able to generate a webhook event using the Webhook simulator and receive it / parse it on my server.

However, when I do a sandbox payment transaction using the client, no webhook event is created (as reflected in the Webhook events list provided in the dashboard), nor it is sent to my server.  Again, my server receives simulated webhooks just fine.

The problem seems to be that the Paypal REST Client is not generating a webhook event.  I have tripled checked everything, but cannot see what I've missed.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. I racked my brain trying to figure out if something was wrong with my code. I contacted Paypal and they said this is an ongoing issue with Paypal sandbox and are working to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Pavi.... I finally contacted Paypal and they gave me the same answer so I'm marking this as accepted.   Based on that convo, I tried it in the live environment and it worked.  Puzzling that they want to move to REST clients but the environment developers need to develop it in is broken.