# Paypal Rest API not triggering webhooks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-webhooks

I've seen a lot of people with this same question and none of the answers solve my issue. I'm making a sale using the [Paypal .Net SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). In my sale I use [this code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Quick-Start) and it works and the process is successfully completed. Then I my success page I execute the payment like this:

```
public ActionResult Success(string paymentId, string token, string PayerID)
{

    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
    apiContext.Config = config;

    var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = PayerID };
    var payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };

    // Execute the payment.
    var executedPayment = payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);

    return View();

}
```

This code is executed without any problem.

My only problem is that my webhook is never triggered. I created the webhook, in the paypal developer dashboard, with all events. When I test with the webhook simulator it gets triggered but when I do the normal process it never does.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: On live the webhook is triggered

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, however I haven't gone live.
By this answer, it is an issue on Paypal's sandbox side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984794/1393652

Hope it will be solved soon.