# Paypal webhooks availability problems on sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

I use paypal REST api and express checkout payments on sandbox.
I set up webhook listener, tested it with webhook simulator and it worked correctly.

When I set up webhook listener, I didn't catch any webhook notifications and on developer dashboard for sandbox, no events were listed (dates until approx. July, 10th 2017). Currently, I get some notifications (not all), but with significant delays.

Is there any problem with webhooks on Paypal's side? I noticed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984794/1393652

I also set up IPN listener and it get IPN notifications almost instantly.
By this comparision: https://devblog.paypal.com/webhooks-for-rest-apis-launched/
, delays are expected with IPN case, not with webhooks.

**Are webhooks re-sent if Paypal's webhook server didn't get response OK (status code 200)?**

Thanks.

Comment: I hear you mate, still in 2020 having same problems.